# How to access method of a class from a generic class?

Tags: java, parameters

I have a class `Creature` which has some methods (getter and setter).
I also have another class `Island<T>` which has a method `feedCreatures`

```
class Island<T> {
    ...
    public void feedCreatures(){
        for(T creature:creatures) {
            creature.setHungry(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't access my method `setHungry()`. Can someone help?

Comment: If you want help, post all the relevant code. We can't see your code if you don't post it.

Answer (score 7):

`class Island<T>` means that `T` derives from `Object`.
To invoke `Creature` methods and more generally that `T` refers to a `Creature` you want that `T` derives from `Creature`.

So this :

```
class Island<T>
```

should be

```
class Island<T extends Creature>
```